# Ubuntu 11.10 - How can i install xserver-xorg-input-evtouch? apt-cache search do not show up

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, installation, package-management, touchscreen

I have Elo touch screen, where i have been trying for long long time, which is failing. I now figure out that i have to use `xserver-xorg-input-evtouch`, which is the only one worked for many others.

But while installing i do not find it under `11.10` and my system is 64-bit. [(Evtouch installation for dual head 1 normal monitor, second one as touch screen, where cursor orientation is breaking.)](http://wiki.linuxmce.org/index.php/ELO_touchscreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Ubuntu 11.10 64-Bit, and I don't see it either. Try searching: `xserver-xorg-input`, and trying one of those packages.